# Forward declarations and incomplete types in C++ modules

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I have been experimenting with C++20 modules, and there seems to be something different with the usual hpp/cpp approach. The following doesn't compile (I'm using the latest preview of MSVC).

foo.ixx

```cpp
export module foo;

import std.memory;

export
struct Bar;

export
struct Foo {
  std::unique_ptr<Bar> ptr;
};
```

bar.ixx

```cpp
export module bar;

import std.core;

import foo;

struct Bar {
  void func(Foo& f) {}
};
```

main.cpp

```cpp
import foo;
import bar;

int main() {
  Foo f;
}
```

My questions:

1. Is there a better way to resolve this other than putting `Foo` and `Bar` into one file?
2. Does this imply that template instantiation is done before module "linking"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules own the declarations placed into them. And if a module owns a declaration, all other declarations must also be part of the same module.

`Bar` was declared to be in `foo`. Therefore, any other declarations of it (and a definition *is* a declaration) must also be within `foo`.

They don't have to be in the same file, but they do have to be in the same module. If you want the definition of `Bar` to be accessible by users of the module `foo`, you should use a module interface unit partition:

```
export module foo:BarDef;

import std.core;

export struct Bar {
  void func(Foo& f) {}
};
```

And the module's primary interface unit must import this partition:

```
export module foo;

import std.memory;

export struct Bar;

export struct Foo {
  std::unique_ptr<Bar> ptr;
};

export import :BarDef;
```

MSVC's naming convention for module files says that `.ixx` should be used for any interface units, so both of these files should be `.ixx` files.